Point-separating fields of clopen sets on compact spaces without Choice
In Matthew Dirk's Paper on Stone's representation theorem there is a proof of
Lemma 3.8. If X is a Stone space and F is a separating field of clopen subsets of
X, then F is the dual algebra of X; that is, it is the field of all clopen subsets of
X.
However this proof uses Choice and I would like to ask if it is nessecary or if something weaker like the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem suffices and if so how would it be done?
mfg dw

Stone's theorem is equivalent to BPI. So, yeah, that should be doable.

This shouldn’t need any choice at all.

This does not require the axiom of choice at all.  First I claim that $F$ separates points and closed sets.  Suppose $x\in X$ and $C\subset X$ is closed and does not contain $x$.  Let $\mathscr{U}$ be the set of elements of $F$ that do not contain $x$.  Since $F$ separates points of $X$, for each $y\neq x$, there is some element of $\mathscr{U}$ that contains $y$.  In particular, $\mathscr{U}$ covers $C$, so by compactness, there are finitely many elements of $\mathscr{U}$ that cover $C$.  The union of these finitely many elements is then an element of $F$ that contains $C$ and does not contain $x$.
Now suppose $A\subseteq X$ is clopen.  Let $\mathscr{U}$ be the set of elements of $F$ that are contained in $A$.  Since $F$ separates each point of $A$ from the closed set $X\setminus A$, for each $x\in A$, there is an element of $\mathscr{U}$ that contains $x$.  Thus $\mathscr{U}$ covers $A$, and by compactness $A$ is a union of finitely many elements of $\mathscr{U}$.  Thus $A\in F$.

Thanks for your help, I was thinking to I have to choose sets to form my cover and didn't relize i could just take all of them

Yes this is a common trick to avoid choice.
